# Gmail API adapted to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to use the gmail API in my react project. I have it setup in React The official docs use a plain Javascript version (http://dpaste.com/15GDH9A).

This file is being called, but I need help rendering the messages in my API

**React attempt**

```
import React from 'react'

window.handleGoogleClientLoad = function() {
  tryAuthorize(/*immediate*/ true);
};

function tryAuthorize(immediate) {
  store.dispatch({type: ActionType.Authorization.REQUEST});
  gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
      /*eslint-disable camelcase*/
      client_id: 'xxx',
      /*eslint-enable*/
      scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
      immediate
    },
    whenAuthenticated
  );
}

function whenAuthenticated(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    store.dispatch({type: ActionType.Authorization.SUCCESS});
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', whenLoaded);
  } else {
    store.dispatch({type: ActionType.Authorization.FAILURE});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it with using loadjs (https://github.com/muicss/loadjs) in a component

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.handleGoogleClientLoad = function() {
    // It's loaded
  }
  loadjs('https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleGoogleClientLoad')
}
```